# An action is not passed from a component to the application

Tags: ember.js

In an Ember 1.13 application, I have this template :

```
{{#each searched_skills as |searched_skill|}}
  {{#skill-card searched_skill=searched_skill delete=delete}}{{/skill-card}}
{{/each}}
```

This controller :

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend
  actions:
    delete: ->
      console.log "test"
```

This template for the component :

```
<div class="col-md-4 well skill">
  <a {{action 'delete'}}>Delete</a>
  <h1>{{searched_skill.skill.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{searched_skill.description}}</p>
</div>
```

And this code the component :

```
export default Ember.Component.extend
  actions:
    delete: ->
      @sendAction 'delete', @get('searched_skill')
```

I want to show "test" in the console when I click on the "delete" button. The "delete" action of the component is triggered but the action of the application controller.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete should be in quotes, and I'd avoid that word, it's a language keyword.

```
{{#skill-card searched_skill=searched_skill delete=`delete`}}{{/skill-card}}
```

Comment: What you mean by "a language keyword"? Which word would you choose?

Comment: It's an operator, and as such is discouraged from being used as a variable name https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete .  Name it whatever you'd like :)  `remove`, `murder`, `obliterate` all seem like they'd work.